# OnModelCreating fails when Context inherits from IdentityDbContext

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-identity-2

I had Data access implemented as below and was working

> 1. Contexct inheriting from DB Context
> 2. Had OnModelCreating for configurations
> 3. Manually addding configurations

However I modified my context to `inherit` from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` and stopped manually generating configurations and after that the OnModelCreating fails and DB updates not happening at all.

If I remove the `OnModelCreating`, it works fine. As soon as I run the application.

Can any one guide me whats going wrong here?

Comment: What's the error? What's in the OnModelCreating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was missing the below line in the OnModelCreating method override. After that it started working.

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```